# how to deploy Email-to-case settings in other sandbox?

Tags: email2case

can we deploy Email to case settings to other sandbox using changeset or any other tool?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 10):

Email-to-Case Settings can be deployed using the [Settings Metadata API Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm?search_text=settings) specifically [CaseSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm).

However, there are issues:

(As of V49)

- No MDAPI support for the default recordtype - you would need to set manually in the target org
- The value of `EmailServicesAddress` in the source org, while it can be (and is) read by the Metadata API, it can not be deployed.  You will get an error if you try and deploy this attribute

  - The workaround is to deploy from your org to Version Control (VCS) first, then manually edit the VCS branch to remove the attribute `<EmailServicesAddress>`. Then deploy from VCS to target org. Such deployment will auto-create an `EmailServicesAddress` that is properly tied to the target org
- The target org Email Address (e.g. `support@mycompany.com`) will still need verifying if new.
- If you are deploying on top of an existing target org E2C email address/`EmailServicesAddress`, the target org's values stay untouched (which is good as otherwise your mail server's forwarding rules would have to be redone)
- Note that deploying `CaseSettings` also deploys all of the `Setup | Objects | Case | Support Settings` -- so be careful to avoid smashing these carefully crafted settings in the target org, especially if PROD

So ... if your deployment tool of choice supports `CaseSettings` (e.g. SFDX, ant, vendor DevOps tools) and you use VCS as an intermediary, then given the above, deployment is possible

Answer (score 5):

No, it looks like we can't deploy them via changesets and any other tool.

The best you can do is deploy via Force.com migration tool is [EmailServicesFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailservicesfunction.htm) which contains `EmailToCase` and `EmailToSalesforce` very basic settings to enable /disable them. They cant be used to specify individual email-to-case services.

One reason I feel they are not part of metadata api is, we have to manually verify the email address for email-to-case and email -services.

You can always raise this as an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideasearch) , with enough upvotes it would be delivered.

Comment: check out my answer and correct me if you have other evidence

Comment: @cropredy sure will investigate